# Allow "shipping address" for downloadable products

Tags: downloadable, shipping-address

For my business model I have a customer group that can buy a software  for its clients. My customer pay for the product and I must to contact the final client for the software installation. For this configuration I need a billing address of my customer and a "shipping address " of the final client but this configuration is not available for this type of products.

Can anyone give me one hint to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you using downloadable products in the first place if you need a shipping address? Are there any other requirements to support this approach?

Comment: Thanks for your help,                                                                        Actually, I don't need a shipping address.        

I'll give one exemple :       

My customer buy a software for his client.For me it's important to have a billing address to send the bill(my customer) and the address of the final client to install the software.    

I hope now it's more clear.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is create two products and bundle them. One your downloadable product and the other a simple product.

You could prevent the products from being purchased individually and set various shopping cart rules (such as free shipping) to achieve whatever end result you require.